# spring boot classnotfound org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper while staring application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am just starting a spring boot project with eureka server as mentioned in https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-microservices-building-microservices-a , While running the project getting below exception and the application is stoped.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper
```

I am using Gradle with springboot 2.3.5.RELEASE version.

Does any one help me why i am seeing this error.

Comment: You've mis spelled Bootstrapper?

Comment: it looks like your gradle setup is not consistent/working : a lacking or conflicting (spring-boot) dependency(?)

Answer (score 5):

There is a conflict between SpringBoot starter web 2.3.5.RELEASE vs spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:3.0.0

After changing SpringBoot starter web 2.4.2, all started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new project with updated dependencies and copy this versions and add to your project

[image]